# How to define a Controller context when testing an ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

I have an ActionResult which works consistently in an MVC 5 project with EntityFramework and Epplus. Clicking an Action link on the View triggers this ActionResult, which sends the selected model to a fresh Excel document.

I am learning to do unit testing my MVC code in Visual Studio 2013 (using the Nuget *Xunit* package) and figured I'd start small, by doing the equivalent of a hello world test on the ActionResult by asserting that the ActionResult is not null.

The test failed with this response: `"System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named 'StudentContext' could be found in the application config file."`

I understand what the error message means, but my question is how I properly define the Controller context in a Testing project. Am I missing something simple and obvious, like defining a context variable, or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

This is the block of code I am using to test my ActionResult.

```
using StudentProject.Controllers;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Xunit;

namespace StudentProject.Tests.Controllers
{
    public class StudentRosterControllerTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ExportToExcel_IsNotNull()
        {
            // Arrange
            StudentRostersController controller = new StudentRostersController();            
            ActionResult ExcelExport;

            // Act
            ExcelExport = controller.ExportToExcel();

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(ExcelExport);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I am testing. It is is an auto-scaffolded controller, with the auto-generated crud methods hidden and the single method to be tested shown.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using StudentProject.Models;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace StudentProject.Controllers
{
    public class StudentRostersController : Controller
    {
        private StudentContext db = new StudentContext();

        // Auto-scaffolded CRUD methods not shown

        // This ActionResult exports the StudentRoster model 
        // to a fresh Excel file.

        public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
        {
            IEnumerable<StudentRoster> query = db.StudentRosters.AsEnumerable();

            using (var excelFile = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet =
                    excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(Collection: query, 
                    PrintHeaders: true);

                // Results in file downloaded to user's default 
                // "My Downloads" folder.
                return File(excelFile.GetAsByteArray(),
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",  
               "Export.xlsx");   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named
>   'StudentContext' could be found in the application config file."

make sure the `app.config` file for the Test project has the proper connection string settings for your EF.

Test project `app.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="StudentContext" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

> how I properly define the Controller context in a Testing project

Your test should try to replicate the run time environment. Provided the minimum needed to test the SUT.

```
namespace StudentProject.Tests.Controllers
{
    public class StudentRosterControllerTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ExportToExcel_IsNotNull()
        {
            // Arrange
            StudentRostersController controller = new StudentRostersController();
            controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
                Controller = controller,
                //...other properties needed for test
            };

            // Act
            var actionResult = controller.ExportToExcel();

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(actionResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Given that you are connecting to your actual database then this would be considered more of an integration test.

I would suggest abstracting your data access so that you can mock it in unit tests.

Comment: What made it work was: (1) installing Entity Framework to my Test Project using Nuget, and (2) copying the copying the connection string to the app.config file. The code as I posed it above works now.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion about abstracting the data access.  Is there a keyword or search term I can use to find a suitable tutorial?

Comment: I would say look for abstracting data access layer.